# Is there some equivalent to {% url 'some-name' %} for router.register(...)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the URL to a specific ViewSet automatically.

I tried using {% url 'api-movement' %} but get the following error:

> Reverse for 'api-movement' not found. 'api-movement' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I searched the web but couldn't really find what I was looking for.

viewset.py

```py
class MovementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovementSerializer
```

router.py

```py
from farm.api.viewsets import *
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('movement', MovementViewSet, base_name='api-movement')
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from farm.api.responder import *

from farm import views
from farm.router import router


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

html excerpt:

```html
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
            });

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "{% url 'api-movement' %}",
                data: {pk: pk},
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (error_data) {
                    alert('An error occurred, please reload page and try again.\n\nError: ' + error_data.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try `api-movement-list` and `api-movement-detail`

Comment: Thanks mate! I can't believe that I spend almost 3 hours on that. Do you have a reference to where I can read about it?

Comment: DRF router register function docs.